# Defer in Go seems to add latency

Tags: go

I am using mutex for synchronisation in Go. Below is the code

```
func (c *MyStruct) Put(key string, value interface{}) {
  c.mu.Lock()
  defer c.mu.Unlock()
  val, found := c.items[key]
  if found {
    item := val.Value.(*Item)
    item.Value = value
    item.Expiration = time.Now().Add(c.ttl).UnixNano()
    return
  }
  ele := c.list.PushFront(&Item{key, value, expirationTime})
  c.items[key] = ele
}
```

When I run a benchmark test on this the output seems is

```
BenchmarkXxx-12      5000000           206 ns/op          37 B/op          2 allocs/op
```

But when I change the code and unlock the mutex manually at the end of the function. It is increasing the performance.

```
BenchmarkLru_put-12     10000000           157 ns/op          26 B/op          2 allocs/op
```

Does defer function add latency to the code? Do I need to avoid the use of defer in this case?

Comment: Yes of course, defer is not free. And whether these 50ns make a difference for your application is something only you can tell.

Comment: It's not 50, just 49 ns ;-)

Comment: For benchmark results, provide the benchmark code and the output from the `go version` command. [Go 1.13 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13): This release improves performance of most uses of defer by 30%.

Comment: "Do I need to avoid the use of defer" - only if you actually have a *measurable performance problem in the overall application that you can trace back to this function*. There are lots of things you can do to make code slightly faster while also making it worse in other ways (more error-prone, harder to read, etc.). Whether or not that's a reasonable trade-off depends on a lot more than what's shown here.

Answer (score 0):

`defer` executes another function, so yes, it adds additional overhead.

You can read more about the details [here](https://medium.com/i0exception/runtime-overhead-of-using-defer-in-go-7140d5c40e32).